# Google Cloud Platform and SAS Enterprise Guide 7.1

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, sas, cloud

Is there a way I can connect and import data from GCP to SAS server?

I am following a manual method of exporting CSV file from GCP and placing it in a folder.
Then running a SAS job to import the data into SAS library.

I want to automate the process of getting data from GCP to SAS automatically.

PS - using SAS Enterprise Guide version 7.1(64 bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use the [BigQuery SAS/ACCESS engine](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/n0bm9s8t6t6rr2n1qgkamlgtb0kk.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the product components that Stu suggests, you should be able to use a REST service on GCP and SAS PROC HTTP.